# What are common difficulties for newbies trying to use Plot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am new to Mathematica, and I have had extreme difficulty with `Plot`. Often, my plots simply don't appear. Here is my current code:

[image: Maximal code example]

I tried to avoid the common problems: for instance, making the functions explicitly depend on `x_`, `y_`, and `c_`. But still, nothing shows up in on the plot.

I did a minimal test with just a single function and without the `Manipulate`, still without any luck:
[image: minimal code example]
Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Please post the code to test.

Comment: In the definition of `PayoffCC` use `SetDelayed` `:=` rather than `Set` `=`.

Comment: Even if one were to type out the code in the image you have posted, it would be impossible to help you without the definitions of the expressions named within the expressions you have posted in image form. Please, type out your code & provide these definitions or a MWE such that it will be better to solve your problem & aid future users in solving their problems as well. Thanks!

Comment: Your `PayoffCC` plot works for me. However, as @RohitNamjoshi said, I would use `:=` in the function definition, to avoid problems with any previous definitions of x, b, or c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using a capital "P" for your function name.

Please try `payoff[x_,b_,c_] =-(c + 2 b (x - 1)) x;`

```
Plot[payoff[x, 4, 2], {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Why are capital function names not allowed? I've used them before without any difficulty.

Comment: The built-in functions of Mathematica all start with a capital letter.  Perhaps Mathematica has a lookup table of built-in functions, and `Plot[ ]` looks there when the function to be plotted starts with a capital letter.

Comment: This is only a problem if you use the same name as a built-in function, which `PayoffCC` is not.  Still better avoided to be on the safe side, but not the actual problem here.

Comment: Then why did `PayoffCC[ ]` not payoff?

Comment: @mjw Did you try it yourself though?! It works perfectly fine!

Comment: Yes, I tried it and got the same result as the OP:  No plot.  Now, after this discussion, tried it again, and it seems to work even with capital letters.  I don't understand what exactly happened.  And my initial try was with $b=4$ and $c=2.$

Answer (score 4):

Something is wrong on your side. It may be lingering definitions, or something else elusive, but **your code works** with the definitions you provided.

I would only recommend NOT starting with $b=0$ and $c=0$, because that will correspond to an empty plot... (Note the explicitly non-zero starting values in the Manipulate below)

```
Pccxx[x_, b_, c_] = c (x - 1) + b (1 - 2 x + 2 x^2)
Pddxx[x_, b_, c_] = -(c + 2 b (x - 1)) x
Pdcxx[x_, b_, c_] = 0. + 0.5 b - 0.5 c

Manipulate[
  Plot[
    {Pccxx[x, b, c], Pddxx[x, b, c], Pdcxx[x, b, c]},
    {x, 0, 1}
  ],
  {{b, 3}, 0, 10},
  {{c, 5}, 0, 10}
]
```

[image: plot with three colored curves as result of Manipulate]